# Cakephp - tree structures generatetreelist blank space spacer

Tags: cakephp

I need to have blank spaces as my spacers in a tree structure.

Here is my code at the moment

```
    $sectors = $this->User->Sector->generatetreelist(null, null, null, '__');    
    $this->Form->input('Sector.user_id', array('options' => $sectors));
```

I tried nsp and also the escaped version.

Any Idea ?

Thanks, Alex

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try an ideographic space: 　, no-break space:   or one of the other [whitespace characters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_%28punctuation%29#Table_of_spaces).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it seems to just output what ever is in there. i.e. it indents with &nbsp;

Comment: @Alex I'm not understanding the problem very well. What's the question?

Comment: When I display a tree structure in a select I need the tree to be indented by a blank space but I can't seem to set a blank space. It works fine with underscores

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
$this->User->Sector->generatetreelist(null, null, null, '&nbsp');
```

then, in your view:

```
$this->Form->input('Sector.user_id', array('options' => $sectors, 'escape' => false));
```